# Как сделать так чтобы бот в телеграме отвечал на все сообщения в том числе на видео и фото? Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Как сделать так чтобы бот в телеграме отвечал на все сообщения в том числе на видео и фото? Aiogram

Есть кусок кода

```
@dp.message_handler(text=('Отчет 1'), state=None)
async def process_start_command(message: types.Message):
   await message.reply('Отправь отчет')
   await FSMAdmin.next()
```

Но он отвечает только на текстовые сообщения.

Если скинуть ему видео или фото ответа нету.

Что делать?

Comment: @dp.message_handler()

Answer (score 1):

Примерно вот так
`@dp.message_handler(content_type=[types.ContentType.ANY])`
Я правда не уверен в регистре.

Answer (score 0):

в

```
@dp.message_handler()
```

просто оставь скобки пустые и всё